# How to change the vertical alignment line in matlab code editor?

Tags: matlab

I want to change the vertical alignment line in matlab code editor in order to have a better illustration when I publish my .m file as html one! how can I do that? I searched but came up with this solution that I use multiple line code writing using "..." notation in my code! 
I should write this way:

```
str = "This sentence is " ...
           "very large one";
```

So I don't want to do that. How can I change its default value.
see the picture below!

[image: Matlab code editor]

thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Matlab Ver**: Matlab 7.8 R2009a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the main window under preferences\Editor\Display you'll find **"Right-hand text limit"**, where you can specify the number of columns between every vertical alignment line.

It's limited to 160 columns, unfortunately.

(ver. Matlab 2013a)

under preferences\Editor\Language you can also find a checkbox "Wrap comments automatically" and some other options just concerning comments. Sometimes the wrapping there also gets annoying.

---

Edit: the 160 columns would exactly fill my screen. So maybe you can choose a bigger value, if you have a bigger resolution/screen.